# Add or change keyboard layout on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I would like to change the keyboard layout on Lubuntu 16.04, that by default  only has the US layout. When I open the Keyboard Layout Handler programme all the controls to change keyboard model or layout are greyed out:

[image]

Is there any other way of adding and changing keyboard layouts on Lubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was only a matter of disabling the *Keep system layouts* option, whose function is a mystery to me.

[image]