# Switching from input language to input language

Tags: 18.04, language-support, input-language

What do I have to do to switch from writing in one language (such as English) to another (such as French) on Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS? I use French and I need to use Arabic.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "*go from language to another*"?

Comment: I mean that I substitute writing in  one language (for example french) by another ( for example arabic)

Comment: See these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216787/how-to-install-select-and-use-different-keyboard-layouts-of-the-same-language-i and https://askubuntu.com/questions/936058/add-or-change-keyboard-layout-on-lubuntu-16-04

Comment: I found the solution in opening  a terminal and typing " setxkbmap ar for Arabic " . But when I want to switch to French, I can't use the terminal to type setxkbmap fr " because the characters on the keyboard are already in Arabic.

Comment: See this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Change_Layout_Option

Answer (score 1):

As for myself, I have to switch between French, English and Russian. I installed all 3 Input sources in Settings/Region & language. I recently discovered I had to press Super Key+Shift+Space to switch keyboard setting.

When there are only 2 input sources, just press Super Key + Space.

Comment: Super+Space should work too.

Comment: Super+Space should work with more than 2 input sources too. Super+Space and Shift+Super+Space do the same thing, but in the opposite directions (left-to-right vs. right-to-left).